# Netsuite throwing error when trying to upload SuiteScript 2.x file (Fail to evaluate script...)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to write a NS script that will loop thru the results of a saved search and update the date expected for a backordered item.  Keeping it simple at the moment to see if I can get the results from the search in the script, but I've run into an issue before I can even test run the script in Netsuite.  When I try to add the file to the file cabinet (and create a script record), I get the error: "Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"missing } after property list (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#33)","stack":[]}"

I'm very new to SuiteScript 2.0 but have had some experience with 1.x.  My script is below, but I have no idea what the error means, or how to fix it.  I've read in a few posts that I need to use return on my callback function and I don't really understand what that is, but I've tried a couple of 'returns' that didn't work (I really don't need the script to return any data, as I can update the records while in the loop).

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 *@NModuleScope Public
 */

require(['N/search', 'N/log'],
    function (search, log) {
        log.debug('Start');
        
        var mySearch = search.load({
            id: 'customsearch_script_update_receive_date'
        });
        
        var myPages = mySearch.runPaged({ pageSize: 1000 });
        for (var i = 0; i < myPages.pageRanges.length; i++) {
            var myPage = myPages.fetch({ index: i});
            myPage.data.forEach(
                function (result) {
                    var internal_id = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[0]);
                    var ns_name = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[1]);
                    var sku = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[2]);
                    var date_expected = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[8]);
                    var quan_expected = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[9]);
                    debugger;
                }
            )   
        }
        
        log.debug('End');
        
        return {
            onRequest : true;
        }
    }
);
```

Latest script as of 3 Nov 2022 09:55 EST
Throwing error: "SuiteScript 2.x entry point scripts must implement one script type function."

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 *@NModuleScope Public
 */

require(['N/search', 'N/log'],
    function (search, log) {
    function actualScript(){
        log.debug('Start');
        
        var mySearch = search.load({
            id: 'customsearch_script_update_receive_date'
        });
        
        var myPages = mySearch.runPaged({ pageSize: 1000 });
        for (var i = 0; i < myPages.pageRanges.length; i++) {
            var myPage = myPages.fetch({ index: i});
            myPage.data.forEach(
                function (result) {
                    var internal_id = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[0]);
                    var ns_name = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[1]);
                    var sku = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[2]);
                    var date_expected = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[8]);
                    var quan_expected = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[9]);
                    log.debug({
                        title: 'Log entry',
                        details: internal_id + ' - ' + ns_name + ' - ' + sku + ' - ' + date_expected + ' - ' + quan_expected
                    });
                }
            )   
        }
        
        log.debug('End');
    }
    
    return {
        execute: actualScript
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a linter to start.

```js
return {
   onRequest : true;
}
```

is not how to write an object literal.
Further a scheduled script function needs to return an `execute` method. (see the script type docs)

e.g.

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 *@NModuleScope Public
 */

define(['N/search', 'N/log'],
    function (search, log) {

        function actualScript(){
            log.debug('Start');
            
            var mySearch = search.load({
                id: 'customsearch_script_update_receive_date'
            });
            
            var myPages = mySearch.runPaged({ pageSize: 1000 });
            for (var i = 0; i < myPages.pageRanges.length; i++) {
                var myPage = myPages.fetch({ index: i});
                myPage.data.forEach(
                    function (result) {
                        var internal_id = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[0]);
                        var ns_name = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[1]);
                        var sku = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[2]);
                        var date_expected = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[8]);
                        var quan_expected = result.getValue(mySearch.columns[9]);
                        debugger;  // does this do anything in a server side script?
                    }
                )   
            }
            
            log.debug('End');
        }
        
        return {
            execute : actualScript
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this information.  It got me a bit closer.  Now, when I upload the script to Netsuite, I get the error: "SuiteScript 2.x entry point scripts must implement one script type function."  Did some research on this and the only entry point on ScheduledScript is 'execute' and that is being used?

`return {
        execute: actualScript
    };
});`

Comment: Sorry. `require` should be `define` for the actual script. Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much.  That did the trick.  Company decided not to hire a Netsuite admin, so it looks like I'll be doing more of this.  Luckily they did pay for the Netsuite training pass, so hopefully I won't have to bother y'all too much.  Thank you again.